# docker run & docker-compose run commands using env variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to use docker-compose run command with assignment of env variable in dynamic way, I.e:

`docker-compose run foo_service -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${OTHER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} /bin/bash`

Reference doc is here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But (per that reference doc you mentioned) the *option* parameters all go *before* the SERVICE and COMMAND parameters, example:

```
docker-compose run --rm -e X=Y SERVICE COMMAND
```